# Using descrete color mapping in stripchart with jitter ontop a boxplot in R

Tags: r, plot, boxplot, jitter

Let's say I want to see the influence of sampling campaigns on the measurement of a variable in a simple graphical way, one way would be to color the events within a strip chart on top of a boxplot. Below is an example code, which works partially. Help greatly appreciated.

````
library(viridisLite)
str(iris)
iris$Cnum <- rep(1:5, length.out=nrow(iris)) # this are  the events/campains I seek to color
boxplot(Sepal.Length ~ iris$Species, data = iris) 
# following I'm introducing the colors I want to use for the 5 different campaigns
Cnum <- c(1:5)
colhex <- viridis(5)
colDf <- data.frame(Cnum, colhex)
iris.draw <- plyr::join(iris, colDf, by = "Cnum")

stripchart(iris.draw$Sepal.Length ~ iris.draw$Species, vertical = TRUE, data = iris.draw, method = "jitter", add = TRUE, pch = 21, cex=0.7 , col = "black", bg = iris$colhex)```
````

I manage to get the points colored in ggplot:

```
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2), colour=iris.draw$colhex)
```

But I'm still struggling with the legend for the color mapping...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (thanks to http://www.sthda.com/):
using the library viridis not viridisLite:

```
library(viridis)

iris.draw$campaign <- as.factor(iris.draw$Cnum)
ggplot(iris.draw, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length, color=iris.draw$campaign)) +
  geom_boxplot(color="black")+
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))+
  scale_color_viridis(discrete=TRUE)
```